# How to set custom error message on array input validation?

Tags: php, validation, laravel

in my form there is dynamic selects and I validate them via Laravel 5 usin `Request` class:

```
$rules = [
   'address' => 'sometimes|required|max:70',
   'area' => 'sometimes|required|numeric|max:10000',
];
foreach ($this->request->get('category') as $key => $val) {
    $rules['category.' . $key] = 'sometimes|required|exists:categories,id';
}
```

But validation errors I can't change and displays something like this:

`Field category.0 is required`, I tried to change `custom` array in `validation.php` file like this:

```
'custom' => [
    'category.0' => [
        'required' => 'Category is required field'
    ],
```

But it didn't change anything.

Comment: Are you using a custom validator or the validate method available in your controller ?

Comment: Thanks, but I already found the solution of my question, see best answer.

Answer (score 0):

To set custom validation message for array input (select in my case)
I used `messages()` method in my `Request` class:

```
public function messages(){
    $messages = [];
    foreach ($this->request->get('category') as $key => $val) {
        $messages['category.'.$key.'.required'] = 'Выберите подраздел';
    }
    return $messages;
}
```