# how I can show custom Error Messages with my validation?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to show a specific error message with my validation as shown (the value already exists, try to write other value) or any message I want.

```php
public function store(Request $request)
         { $excuse->coursenum = $request->input('coursenum');
         $validatedData = $request->validate([
         'coursenum' => Rule::unique('students')->where(function ($query) {
             return $query->where('status_id', 2);
         })
         ]);
         $messages = [
'coursenum.required' => 'the value is alredy exite, try to write othe value',
      ];
 $excuse->save();
        return redirect('/students');
         }
```

and add in my blade this code

```php
@if ($errors->any())
  <div class="alert alert-danger">
    <ul>
        @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
          <li>{{ $error }}</li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
  </div>
@endif
```

Comment: It's much better to use dedicate form request class for handling that. Third parameter of validate method is for custom messages.

Answer (score 1):

**At Controller File**

```
    $request->validate([
        'coursenum' => [Rule::unique('students')->where('status_id',2)],

         ['coursenum.unique'=>"Put Your Custom Message Here"]
    ])
```

**At Blade File**

```
@if($errors->has('coursenum')
     <span class='help-block'>
        <strong> {{ $errors->get('coursnum') }} </strong>
     </span>
```

Note : You may try with create Request File too for custom Validation message .

Answer (score 0):

```
   public function messages(){
   $messages = [];
   foreach ($this->request->get('category') as $key => $val) {
    $messages['category.'.$key.'.required'] = 'Выберите подраздел';
    }
     return $messages;
    }
```

[How to set custom error message on array input validation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34514215/how-to-set-custom-error-message-on-array-input-validation)

[How to set custom error message with form_validation And CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646553/how-to-set-custom-error-message-with-form-validation-and-codeigniter/3649517)

https://laraveldaily.com/how-to-customize-error-messages-in-request-validation/

https://hdtuto.com/article/php-laravel-set-custom-validation-error-messages-example

https://www.sitepoint.com/setting-custom-error-messages-for-zend_form_element/

https://laravel.io/forum/07-27-2014-custom-validation-messages-with-data-of-the-rules

These links hold info & some hold source code for PhP Validation Error Messages

I hope this helps you :)